# Redirection Based on Condition

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Okay this is really getting to me now. My page does nothing when it's supposed to re-direct depending on a condition. The conditions are reached and I can print a message depending on a True or False result. But the re-directs simply aren't working. Everything I've looked at is telling me there's no reason why the codes not working but it simply isn't. I've tried on but Firefox and Chrome as well as getting a friend to try it on his PC. It simply hits a wall when it reaches the re-direction.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to get a time-based greeting.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
       function myFunction()
       {
         var x="";
         if(new Date("2014-03-04 21:00:00") < new Date())
         {
            x="GOOD";
         }
         else
         {
            window.location = "//www.google.com"
         }
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
      }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd appreciate any help as I'm extremely new to HTML & Javascript. But could people please make sure there solution works at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_redirect) by copying there code into it and submitting it and obviously hitting the button.

Comment: The above code works for me.  W3schools's HTML/JS sandbox seems to prevent redirects to other websites.

Comment: Your code works perfectly well in it self – so my guess is that there might be some important part of information that you are withholding from us … like for example, is that code maybe displayed in some kind of (i)frame? (Google does not _want_ you to to display their pages in any kind of frames, and so they tell your browser not to do that via an `X-Frame-Options` header …)

Comment: When I run it the bottom left of the browser says waiting for www.google.com and then it disappears and nothing happens. Is there any way to force the page to change?

Comment: The code is ran in an iframe/HTML/JavaScript app. My site is hosted by a webmaster (wix.com) and so I don't have access to the base code of the site. I thought this would force the entire page to change and not just the iframe...?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your last comment, it sounds like you want the entire page to redirect, not just the iframe.  So, you can force the parent window to change by replacing

```
window.location = "//google.com"
```

with

```
window.top.location = "//google.com"
```

Using `top` tells JavaScript to execute this on the parent.  This works in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v54bK/), so it should work on your site as well.